# why newly instance(object) is created when constructor exits?

Tags: c++, object, constructor

I was asked in an interview why a new object is created when the constructor exits?

I said that when we declare object for any class, memory is created in stack or heap at run time.  As soon as memory is created, the constructor is called, and when it finishes, it returns the new object because the space is filled with the contents of constructor initialization and thus the new object.

I would be heartily thankful if some one explain maybe what the interviewer was asking for?

Comment: One can't directly call a constructor, nor do constructors return anything.  I think this is a trick question, the new operator evaluates to a pointer to the new object, but that's not quite the same thing.  Although, conversion operators and constructors can be used to evaluate to an instance by value, that might be what they're referring to.

Comment: This might be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: please don't vote down if possible help me to understand it i am new here plz

Comment: @user3784175: Posting a question about something you don't understand doesn't earn downvotes.  Posting a question where we don't understand exactly what your asking is what invokes downvotes.  Please try to clarify the question.

Comment: The interviewer's question makes no sense to me. "Why is a new object created when you create a new object?" Maybe there was a (human) language issue. I would have asked for clarification.

Comment: @MooingDuck i m sorry  i have  edited what all i mean was why newly instance is returned when constructor exit?

Comment: @user3784175: It isn't.  Either (A) you misunderstood the question (B) you misremember the question, or (C) it was a trick question.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer to that interview question is that a constructor doesn't return anything.
A class' constructor is called when an object of its type is initialized. At that point the memory region to construct the object in is already reserved and the address known. There's therefore no need for the constructor to return anything unless there's an error condition, which can be reported through an exception.
The constructor's only job is to write useful values to that memory region and usually establish an invariant of the class that is maintained by copy and move operations.
To do its job a constructor will at first call its parent's constructor, which in turn will call its parent constructor, up to the top of the inheritance hierarchy. In case of multiple inheritance, the parent constructors are called in the order of their declaration. For virtual inheritance the constructor of the virtual class will be called first to ensure that it's properly initialized wherever it's used within the class hierarchy.
Once the parent constructors finished, the class' members are initialized in the order of declaration and finally the constructor's own body is executed.
Destruction is done in reverse order and only what's completely constructed is destroyed.
An object is completely constructed, once its constructor finishes.
Therefore if a member or parent constructor throws, or if you throw an exception in the constructor's body, all members and parents that were successfully created up to that point will be properly destroyed in the reverse order of their construction.
In case of allocation using new, the memory for the object will be freed and the exception re-thrown.

As you can see a constructor just initializes the memory of an object about which you already know how to access it (usually through a variable) and therefore it never returns any value.

To add an example:

```
class T : private parent {
    U member_first;
    V member_second;
};

T foobar() {
    T a{};
    return a;
}
```

This will explicitly construct an object of type T using the default constructor.
The function within which the variable a is defined will have sizeof(T) bytes reserved on the stack (Assuming the machine has a stack ;) ) when it is invoked. So far no constructors were invoked.
Now when the default constructor gets called, the this pointer for the object named a is set to the value of &a and a constructor default-defined like this is executed:

```
T::T() : parent{}, member_first{}, member_second{} {}
```

I hope this example makes it clear, that rather than having the constructor return something, it is implicitly given the address of the memory area that has to be initialized, similarly like a function returning void, that takes a pointer as an argument and changes the value pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

The new object (a reference to the created object) is returned that you

1. can copy and assign it to other object
2. can apply other methods of the class to the created object.

Shortly speaking that you could create temporary objects used in expressions.

Consider an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::string( "Hello ").append( "World!" ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

A constructor call is an expression and it has type distinct from void.

Comment: _'The new object is returned ...'_ Constructors don't return anything, they're initializing memory layout and execute statements from their definitions. But they don't return anything.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  If you would be right then you could not deal with temporary objects and you could not apply other methods as for example std::string().append( "Hello" );

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i know but when  when the constructor exits, the runtime returns the newly-created instance. So the reason the constructor doesn't return a value is because it's not called directly by your code, it's called by the memory allocation and object initialization code in the runtime. Its return value (if it actually has one when compiled down to machine code) is opaque to the user - therefore, you can't specify it.

Comment: _'... then you could not deal with temporary objects'_ There are various ***allocation*** methods available: stack allocation, temporary objects, `new()`, but these are actually independent of the constructor method called using the allocated space.

Comment: @user3784175 You can't call a constructor explicitly, so it doesn't make any sense for it to have any return value. The function signature shows that as well.

Comment: @user3784175 _'... the runtime returns ...'_ Which runtime?!? Everything's working well on my bare metal system's call stacks.

Comment: @triple_r sorry we can call constructor explicitly i will give u an example     class sample
  {
    int i;
   public:

   sample(int i=0)
    {

        }
 };
  void main()
   {
    sample s; // ipplicit call
    s=sample(3); // explicit call
   }

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it is called by memory allocation and object initialization code in the runtime

Comment: @user3784175 I should have been more clear about my comment. "Constructor is invoked only once per object, and cannot be called after that". Your example is just a different kind of constructor, a copy constructor that uses a temp object created by `sample(3)`. The temp object is not "returned" by the constructor, it is just "created" by it.

Comment: @user3784175 Again, which runtime? I have well working bare metal code without any OS / _"runtime"_ that well allocates the memory necessary for these instances just on the call stack. Take a look at [@foobar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24895859/1413395), he's got it right closest IMHO.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: §5.2.3/1 "If the expression list specifies more than a single value, the type shall be a class with a suitably declared constructor, and the expression `T(x1, x2, ...)` is equivalent in effect to the declaration `T t(x1, x2, ...)`; for some invented temporary variable `t`, with the result being the value of `t` as a prvalue."  The expression calls the constructor, and evaluates to a value.  The constructor does not return the value.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I believe he's using "runtime" to refer to the "invisible" code added by the compiler to cause everything to work, such as exceptions, stack unwinding, typeinfo, the conversion constructor calling the constructor, and such.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ at complie time look up table is created but at run time memory is reserved in stack.so memory is allocated in stack at runtime and my question was when constructor exit, new object is created ? this object is not created directly by our code but by the memory allocation and object initialization code?

Comment: @Mooing Duck  The fact that the constructor has no return statement with a value does not mean that the expression with constructor call has no type.:) it is two different thins. I showed you example. According to you the example has no sense.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: You're referring to the example of `std::string( "Hello ")`?  §5.2.3 says that's an "explicit type conversion" expression, which constructs a value of the specified type, and evaluates to the value constructed. There's also details in that section about how with `void` no initialization is done, and if it evaluates to an lvalue, rvalue, or prvalue.  Seeing as how primitives (and `void`!) have no constructors, such syntax is obviously not a direct constructor call.

Comment: @Mooing Duck  It is a direct constructor call and nothing more. Simply such constructors which can be called with one parameter are called conversion constructors.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Section 5.2.3 "Explicit type conversion (functional notation)" also covers conversions that use multiple parameters.  Also, primitives and void do not have constructors to call, and yet `int(4)`, and even `void()` is valid.  The expression constructs them, but is not itself a direct constructor call. (I just noticed you said previously "...does not mean that the expression with constructor call has no type". That is accurate. The expression definitely has a type, we're in agreement there)

Comment: @Mooing Duck You are wrong. "1 Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion functions". So there is a call of a constructor and nothing more.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: §12.3/1?  I believe that specification is referring to how type conversion methods of a class are implemented, not necessarily how they're called.  However, now that you have a standards quote that makes this more ambiguous, it might be time for us to post a new question.  I'll post one momentarily.

Comment: @Mooing Duck There is no any magic wand. There is called a constructor. At least try to use the debug mode that to see what is called.

Comment: @Mooing Duck it seems that you do not understand thet in this expression std::string( "Hello" ) an object of type std::string is created. That to create the object the corresponding constructor shall be called. There is no any "magic wand".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57788/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-vlad-from-moscow).